# How does a SSL Certificate Authority know that you own the domain?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ca

What is stopping one from getting a signed SSL certificate to a domain he/she does not own?

I.e. What checks are made to make sure one cannot simply buy a new certificate for google.com and go about doing evil...

Surely the whole point of giving (a ridiculous sum of) money to a CA is so that people are without doubt that the server they are connecting to is the correct one.  No?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is up to the CA to ensure that the person applying for a certificate own the domain.

One method that is often being used for cheap SSL certificates is [whois lookup](http://whois.net/)

But methods can vary from CA to CA and the level of trust the certificate gives.

Comment: Another method they use is to email the owner of record as recorded in the DNS and ask for confirmation.